# Loop Wordpress Taxonomy Followed With Relationship Field Type ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I have two custom post type, the name is: University and Programs.

In my plugin for programs post type, I insert register_taxonomy functions, and the name is program_categories.

So, I can give categories for each programs post. For Example: Information Technology Categories, for Website Development and Application Development Post Type.

And then, I create relationship field type using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin filtered by my Programs Custom Post Type.

Actually, I can display every programs post type using this code:

```
 $university_programs = get_field('university_programs');

 foreach($university_programs as $university_program){
 echo $university_program->post_title;
 }
```

And the output will be like this:

1. Website Development
2. Application Development
3. Archeology

I don't want to be like that.. I want it to displayed like this:

1. Information Technology
   1.2) Website Development
   1.3) Application Development
2. Humanities
   2.1) Archeology

I can use details and summary so on frontend won't be too long.

Actually, I have code like this:

```
   $terms = get_terms('program_categories', array(
            'parent' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'number'=> -1
        ));
     foreach($terms as $term){
    $programs = new WP_QUERY(array(
                            'post_type' => 'programs',
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'program_categories' => $term->name
                        ));
while($programs->have_posts()){
$programs->the_post();
echo the_title
}
    }
```

But that displaying all categories and program post title.

How to display program categories that university have followed with relationship post type?

Comment: Please leave initial greeting formulas and other similar stuff out of your questions, that is just noise.

Comment: Sure.. I thought there is something wrong before.

Comment: Do you want to list _all_ the categories each time, even if there might not be any posts in some of them? Or do you want to list only those, that actually have posts? In the first case, you should start by getting a list of your categories; in the other, you will need to get all the categories from your selected posts first.

Comment: I want to list program category that the university have the the relationship field type.
If only list all category, I can use get_terms functions.

Comment: Can each post only have one category - or multiple?

Comment: can be multiple category for each post.

Comment: Then you should assemble your posts grouped by category first. Keep looping over $university_programs, but don't echo in there. Instead, get the categories associated with the current post, and then loop over those. Stick the posts into a new array, `$grouped[category name here][] = $university_program->post_title;` That gives you a two-dimensional array of post titles grouped under there category name - so loop over that again using two nested loops, and output the data.

Comment: can you give example link to learn?

Comment: Learn what, exactly?

Comment: Can I use get_the_term_list() to solve my problem? @CBroe

Comment: I tried it, but the result somewhat like this:

1) Information Technology
1a) Web Development
2) Information Technology
2a) Application Development

Comment: Well, not to output the same category twice, is something you still have to implement. The basic keyword here is _control break_.